# j2ee agent is blocking to start tomcat 7 error 1067

Tags: java, tomcat, javaagents

i installed `openAM 12` and configured the `agent profile and policy` in `windows server2008 r2 x64`. I installed `apache-tomcat-7.0.55.gz` from windows `command prompt`.Now, i installed the `Tomcat-v6-7-Agent-3.3.0` successfully.but when i tried to start the `tomcat server` from my `service.msc`.it's showing error like `"windows cannot start tomcat 7.0 tomcat 7 to your local computer`.error 1067".i please help.

Comment: may be i can not deploy OpenAM and OpenAM J2EE agent in the same Tomcat instance.then how will i install it

Comment: not working.i installed another instance of tomcat in some other port like 9080.my agent url is http://sso.example.com:9080/myapps.   myapps is the folder where my servlets and html pages are there.but stil the another tomcat server is not working